# Is it possible to bind two socket ports at the same time and setup a bypass connection between in localhost

Tags: python, sockets

I have a client-server socket program running but with different TCP ports.
I am using python scripts to listen data coming from client, say socket# 5254 for example, then send the data to its server at socket# 5255.
Later on, will use the over socket data and send it to a device on SMBus using a tool in the test machine.  First is to test the bridge mode with both Data-over-Socket connection. Scipt is something like below. Question: How to bind two Ports at the same time in Host (use a Windows 10 PC) ?

```
import socket, time
TIMEOUT = 60*1000  # timeout 1 minutes 60*1000 ms'
req = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
req.bind(('localhost', 5254))
req.listen()
req_conn, req_addr = req.accept()
with req_conn:
   print('Connected by', req_addr)

res = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
res.bind(('localhost', 5255))
res.listen()
res_conn, res_addr = res.accept()
with res_conn:
  print('Connected by', res_addr)

while True:
  t = 0
  req_data = req_conn.recv(1024)
  req_conn.sendall(res_data)
  res_data = res_conn.recv(1024)
  res_conn.sendall(req_data)
  time.sleep(0.001) # delay 0.001 second
  if t >= TIMEOUT: break
req.close()
res.close()
```

When I run client and server program separately with two port 5253/5254, scripts stopped after the first  connection. What is the right way to bind two socket ports, and setup a bypass bridge connection between them in Python (use Python 3.6) ?

Comment: You are sending all the data back where it came from. Surely you should be receiving from `req_conn` and sending to `res_conn`, and then *vice versa*. Also you are ignoring end of stream, on which you should close both sockets and exit the loop.

Comment: Thank you ! Receive data from 5253 and send it to 5254. Then receive data from 5254 to send it back to 5253. It is bidirection SPDM protocol. The problem is the res_conn is basically a connection listening to port 5254. I am unable to set up a connection to that port.

Comment: Are both peers really going to connect to your listening ports? Surely one of them is a server and you should connect to it?